# How do I map an index created by fscrawler so that I can do exact full text search on the document?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, fscrawler

I have an index of binary files created by fscrawler(has a default mapping).

I am querying my index using php-elasticsearch:

```
if ($q2 == '') {
  $params = [
    'index' => 'trial2',
    'body' => [
       'query' => [
        'term' => [
          'content' => $q
              ]
        ]
    ]
];

$query = $client->search($params);
$data['q'] = $q;
}
```

I am trying to do an exact full text search on the content field (body). how do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change the default mapping and use a `keyword` data type for the `content` field. That being said, it won't allow searching for individual terms anymore.

Is that really what you want?

May be what you are after is actually using a `match` query instead of a `term` query?